# How can I convert this array-like string to real array?

Tags: javascript

I have got value from parameter. it really is %5B21,75%5D but when I see in console.log, it seems like that value is equivalent to:

```
var str = "[12,15]";
```

So I can't use any function of array with this string.
How can I convert this string to real array like

```
var str = [12,15];
```

Comment: have you tried eval(str)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `eval()`.

`var arr = eval("[12,15]");`

Answer (score 2):

In this case, `JSON.parse(val)` will work fine.